# What's the difference between += and =+

Tags: java

I am wondering what is the difference between these two assignment operators. A simple and right to the point answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The first one is an assignment operator, the second one isn't.

Comment: `=+` is not an operator. It is the assignment operator (`=`) followed by the unary plus operator (`+`).  `+=` *is* an operator. In the expression `a += b`, it stores the result of `a + b` in `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Expression `a =+ b` is equal to `a = +b`, which is the same as `a = b`.

Expression `a += b` is equal to `a = a + b`

Comment: Thanks for clearing my confusion.